# Jquery load() Method with text

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, function, load

How to display file.txt content with any text on `<title id="mytitle"></title>` tag

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
     $("#mytitle").load("/file.txt");
});
```

file.txt

```
My Brother
```

I want to do this

```
<title id="mytitle">My Brother is Big</title>
```

How can I add "**is big**" text to title tag?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can `append()` the extra words in the callback function of `load()` which is invoked after the AJAX request has completed and added the content.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  let $mytitle = $("#mytitle").load("/file.txt", () => $mytitle.append(' is big'));
});
```

The only thing to note here is that you're attaching the `load()` call to the window.load event, which may mean that the DOM is not fully loaded before you try and update it, depending on how quickly your server responds to the AJAX request. It would be safer to perform the call in document.ready instead:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $mytitle = $("#mytitle").load("/file.txt", () => $mytitle.append(' is big'));
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Sorry for disturb but if I want to do "is Big My Brother"  I want to put "is Bİg" on first

Comment: Change `append()` to `prepend()`

Comment: You are perfect! Thanks for your help.